# How to understand output of ArcGIS System Monitor?

Tags: arcgis-server, performance

We had some performance issues with our enterprise ArcGIS server application, in this regard I have installed **[ArcGIS System Monitor v1.0.9](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=848f48b0f88e4de7a036377197453efe)**. After installing and configuring the site, they are several variables (below). I would like to know how these variables effect the performance and their definitions. Please throw some light on this.

ARCGIS Percent Processor Time
ARCGIS Working Set GB
ARCGIS Active Working Set GB
ARCGIS Instance Count
ARCGIS Active Instance Count
ARCGIS Idle Instance Count
ARCGIS Virtual GB
ARCGIS Private GB
ARCGIS Page File GB
ARCGIS Page Faults/sec
ArcSOC Percent Processor Time
ArcSOC Working Set GB
ArcSOC Active Working Set GB
ArcSOC Active Instance Count

Comment: Ooh shiny. There goes my week.

Comment: nef001- Any help??